# Wordpress Text is not Shows line by line

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I write a custom type for wordpress which is contain a textarea. I can save it and also i can access from single view. But i want to show them line by line if author save it line by line. But it's not showing them line by line, it shows all of them as a single line.

Here is my single.php's custom meta show codes;

```
             <div id="yemek_resim">
                    <?php if($tz_image_display == 'true') : ?>

                    <?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) : /* if post has post thumbnail */ ?>

                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('single-large'); ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </div><!-- yemek_resim -->
        <div id="yemek_malzemeleri">
        <?php
        $malzemeler = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ofa_yemek_malzemeler', true);
        echo esc_attr($malzemeler);
        ?>
        </div><!-- yemek_malzemeleri -->
```

here yemek_malzemeler's content come from a textarea and author can write multiline content. But at site, they seem as a single line...

Comment: Can you show and example of the output and the expected output? Wordpress' text editor has its own way of going about line breaks.

Comment: i'm not using wordpress' text editor, i'm using custom meta box and html5 textarea field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by using `<pre> </pre>` tags.  thanks for your care.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the N2BR PHP function in the output file. Just write `<?php echo n2br($string); ?>` in the `single.php` file from Wordpress. Good luck ;)

Comment: Now i tried it but now it's looking like this,

asd<br /> dasf<br /> asdf<br /> asdf<br /> asd<br /> fasd<br /> f<br /> asdf
asdfadf

Comment: Okay, so then apply the n2br on the output file, where text is supposed ot be shown. and delete it from the action file.

Comment: i applied on the outpu file but how can i delete it from action file?

Comment: Where did you originally pasted the n2br? I thought you did on your action file, which is used in `<form method="post" action="THE_ACTION_FILE.php">`

Comment: Just apply it on single.php file

Comment: now i tried this, but again i'm seeing the </ br> codes on page... :(

Comment: I resolved the problem by using <pre> </pre> tags. :) thanks for your care :)

Comment: Yes because it is getting repeated, on database it has already been modified. try writing a new post or tell me the link so I can help you